# js creating map object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a map of objects to use by the following code:

```js
var MARKED ={className: 'emoji', img:'⚐'} ;
var EMOJI_WONDER = {className: 'emoji', img: ''};
var EMOJI_WIN = {className: 'emoji', img: ''};

var emoMap={};
emoMap[EMOJI_WONDER]=EMOJI_WONDER;
emoMap[MARKED]=MARKED;
emoMap[EMOJI_WIN]=EMOJI_WIN;
console.log(emoMap);
```

and i get object object.
I've made a map before with the following code:

```js
var str = 'this is a test la la la la lo';
var wordMap = countWordApperances(str);
console.log(str, 'got: ', wordMap);

function countWordApperances(txt) {
    var wordCountMap = {};
    
    var words = txt.split(' ');
    
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var currWord = words[i];
        if (wordCountMap[currWord]) wordCountMap[currWord]++;
        else wordCountMap[currWord] = 1;

    }
    return wordCountMap;
}
```

and i just can't tell why the top code won't set a map and the bottom code does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
emoMap[EMOJI_WONDER]=EMOJI_WONDER;
```

you're using `EMOJI_WONDER` as both the key (name) of the property and its value. Property names can only be strings or Symbols, they cannot be objects. So when you do that, `EMOJI_WONDER` is coerced to string to form a property name. Since all of your objects are plain objects, they all coerce to the same string: `"[object Object]"`. That's why your `emoMap` ends up with only one property.

Perhaps you meant to use the variable names as the property names:

```
emoMap.EMOJI_WONDER = EMOJI_WONDER;
// or
emoMap["EMOJI_WONDER"] = EMOJI_WONDER;
```

If not, you probably want an array or `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

You have pass a variable object as a key for the object `emoMap`,you need to use string as key instead

```js
var MARKED ={className: 'emoji', img:'⚐'} ;
var EMOJI_WONDER = {className: 'emoji', img: ''};
var EMOJI_WIN = {className: 'emoji', img: ''};

var emoMap={};
emoMap["EMOJI_WONDER"]=EMOJI_WONDER;//add quote to make it work
emoMap["MARKED"]=MARKED;
emoMap["EMOJI_WIN"]=EMOJI_WIN;
console.log(emoMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in top case is that :

`.toString()` gets called and on `MARKED`, `EMOJI_WONDER` and `EMOJI_WIN` before using it as a key. Therefore, all assignments get loaded upon the same key. Viz: `'[object Object]'`.

Hence, when you print the output is:

```
{
    '[object Object]': {
        className: 'emoji',
        img: ''
    }
}
```

The final assignment (`EMOJI_WIN`)